# Append value or create and insert if the list doesn't exist?

Tags: python, list

I found myself always writing this kind of ugly snippet when I have to insert a value to a non-existing list:

```
if hasattr(obj, 'key'):
    obj.key = []
obj.key.append(value)
```

Of course, I could use `defaultdict(list)`, but in this use-case I cannot do it a priori.

Is there a more pythonic yet simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: `obj.key = getattr(obj, 'key', [])`? I'd first and foremost say your objects might need a more predictable structure, to render this problem moot…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `setdefault` on the instance dict, i.e.

```
vars(obj).setdefault('key', []).append(value)
```